# Unable to build catkin workspace; python-rosdep, no module terminal_color

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep, catkin, catkin-make-isolated, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm running into an error when installing ROS (melodic) on Ubuntu (18.04). As I have absolutely no experience with UNIX, I don't really know what's going on or how to fix it.

First, I tried installing it with `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full` but that didn't work because it wasn't found. Following the suggestion of an online post, I switched to installing it from source.

**AddOn:** Sorry that I haven't mentioned that in advance (didn't make the connection):
I'm running Ubuntu on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and I already have Python3 installed on windows. Ref. comment in [this ROS Answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/294146/importerror-when-running-catkin_make_isolated/). How can I check whether this is the problem?

Now I'm following these instructions:
[melodic installation from source](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Source)

Everything worked up to point *2.1.1 Resolving Dependencies*. Doing this step (again), I get the info:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rosdep]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-rosdep2' instead of 'python-rosdep'
python-rosdep2 is already the newest version (0.11.8-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rosdep]
```

Then I proceed with the installation tutorial trying to build the catkin workspace:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 12, in <module>
    from catkin.builder import build_workspace_isolated
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 66, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import ansi, disable_ANSI_colors, fmt, sanitize
ImportError: No module named terminal_color
```

This is my Ubuntu release:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
```

---

According to the answer from 130s I tried the command `sudo apt-get update`, but that didn't work initially due to a key not being available:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for stivari:
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease [4031 B]
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Adding the key solved this and rosdep runs successfully after `sudo apt-get update`:

```
$ curl -sL "http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x5523BAEEB01FA116" | sudo apt-key add
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease [4031 B]
Get:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [305 kB]
Fetched 309 kB in 4s (73.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

~/ros_catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro melodic -y
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-rosdep]
[sudo] password for stivari:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python-rosdep2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-rosdep
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 46.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python-rosdep all 0.12.2-1 [46.7 kB]
Fetched 46.7 kB in 1s (49.4 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 122878 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-rosdep2 (0.11.8-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-rosdep.
(Reading database ... 122834 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-rosdep_0.12.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-rosdep (0.12.2-1) ...
Setting up python-rosdep (0.12.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

But after that, I'm running into the same error:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated", line 12, in <module>
    from catkin.builder import build_workspace_isolated
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 66, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import ansi, disable_ANSI_colors, fmt, sanitize
ImportError: No module named terminal_color
```

---

If you need any additional info, please ask and tell me how to get them.

Thanks,
Andre

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304006/unable-to-build-catkin-workspace;-python-rosdep,-no-module-terminal_color/) by [AndreKissling](https://answers.ros.org/users/37655/andrekissling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-09-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-23**:\

> Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)

When you see something like this you need to run the commands in admin mode. Add `sudo` in the beginning of the command (that's Linux basics so you can find lots of info by Googling the error message ;)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-24**:\

> I'm following these instructions: melodic installation **from source**

First question: why do you want to install Melodic from sources on Ubuntu 18, for which binary packages are available (ie: simple `apt install ros-melodic-****`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> First, I tried installing it with `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full` but that didn't work because it wasn't found. Following the suggestion of an online post, I switched to installing it from source.

I would *strongly* recommend to not install from sources. Especially not under WSL. It's very slow, and you'll spend way too much time managing your installation.

A binary installation is *almost always* preferred over building things from sources.

`desktop_full` has been released into Melodic (see [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=full](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=full) fi), so if you couldn't install that, I'm wondering whether you setup your system correctly.

Please figure out whether you have a need for installing ROS from sources, and if you don't, I would revert whatever you already have done and we should try to figure out why `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full` didn't work for you, **not** start a source install and diagnosing problems with that.

---

Edit: just noticed this:

> I tried the command `sudo apt-get update`, but that didn't work initially due to a key not being available

If the key also wasn't available the first time you tried `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full`, then that was the reason why `apt` couldn't find the package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreKissling](https://answers.ros.org/users/37655/andrekissling/) on 2018-09-27**:
After adding the key manually it was possible to install it using `apt-get install`.
Thanks!